# Student can't see any course in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, learndash, buddyboss

I'm using learnDash and BuddyBoss. I added course and enrolled some students in it.

Problem: Only admin role can see lesson form and other role user can see only progress bar.

[image]

Could you help me to fix it out, I already checked out documenations of LearnDash and BuddyBoss.

Check the screenshot...

[image]